# How to dynamically generate an app theme based on MediaQuery?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to be able to change the size of text based on the size of the screen, which you can get by calling `MediaQuery.of(context)`. However, this is not accessible in the initial build method of the app. Is there a nice way to dynamically generate the theme at runtime?

Comment: have you see this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html ?

Comment: Awesome that's exactly what I needed!